# radare2 Loop over literal strings for search

Tags: radare2

In radare2, I can search and grep e.g. `/ needle ~:0 2>/dev/null`.  How I can I do that in a loop for multiple needles? E.g. something like `for n in needle1 needle2 needle3; do / $n ~:0 2>/dev/null; done`.

(The `2>d/dev/null` is to quiet the play-by-play messages as radare2 searches; I couldn't find an option to do so)